# ggplot2 y axis label decimal precision

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting several ggplot charts in a loop (i know, i know don't loop use plyr...but) and was curious if there was a way to set the decimal precision to say one decimal (i.e. 0.0).  I am using the following scale transformation.

```
p <- p + scale_y_log10()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was kind of under the impression that one decimal (i.e 1.2) was the default, but if you're seeing more decimal places than that, you can pass your own formatting to the scale:

```
fmt_dcimals <- function(decimals=0){
   # return a function responpsible for formatting the 
   # axis labels with a given number of decimals 
   function(x) as.character(round(x,decimals))
}
```

And then add the scale to your plot:

```
ggplot( ... ) + scale_y_log10(labels = fmt_dcimals(2))
```

Now that I think about this, I should add that if you're really going to write your own formatter, you should probably stick to using the `format` function to do the work, rather than rounding and coercing. That's probably safer and "nicer".

As an example, to force two digits after the decimal, you could change this formatting function to something like this:

```
fmt_dcimals <- function(decimals=0){
    function(x) format(x,nsmall = decimals,scientific = FALSE)
}
```

and you can further play with the `nsmall` and `digits` arguments to `format` to get what you want, I think. An example of it's use:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5,y = rexp(5))
ggplot(df,aes(x = x,y=y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_y_log10(labels = fmt_dcimals(2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. For consistency in axis appearance I would like to always have two decimals even if the number rounds evenly to one decimal.  Is there a way to make the round function always return two decimals (i.e.  round (22.50,2) returns 22.5 instead of 22.50)?

Comment: @MikeTP Sorry for the delay. I think my edit addresses your question.

Comment: why do you have a function within a function?

Comment: @naught101 The more recent versions of ggplot were rewritten such that the `labels` argument to most `scale_*` functions takes a _function_ as a value. In the associated **scales** package you will find lots of formatting functions that actual return functions that are used to format labels. In short, wrapping it in `fmt()` makes our code in `scale_*` much more concise, compared to writing out the whole function as an argument to `scale_*`.

Comment: @joran: that makes no sense to me. Why wouldn't you just to `fmt<-function(x){format(x,nsmall = 2,scientific = FALSE)} ; ggplot(df,aes(x = x,y=y)) +  scale_y_log10(labels = fmt)`? (note missing `()` from scale call). It does exactly the same thing, but it passes the function directly to ggplot, instead of passing a function that passes a function.

Comment: @naught101 For this particular example, you're right, it's doesn't matter much. But that's just because we don't need to pass any arguments through. Consider `date_format`. If we do what you describe with that one, how do we pass different date formats along? Now consider an even more complicated example, like `math_format`. So I was just sticking with the conventional format, that's all.

Comment: Nice use of a closure. Via the `partial` function from the `pryr` package you can get similar behavior in much shorter code: `labels = partial(sprintf, fmt = '%0.2f')`.