# ggplot: align plots together and add common labels and legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `data.frame` in which one variable has many levels (e.g. `param1`, `param2`and `param3`). All these levels have the same unit (concentration mg L-1) but they have different ranges of values.

For example

`param1` ranges from `0` to `0.4`

`param2` ranges from `0` to `0.07`

`param3` ranges from `0` to `3000`

Instead of using my data.frame, I used `diamonds` to create a reproducible example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- diamonds %>%
  dplyr::filter(cut%in%c("Fair","Ideal")) %>%
  dplyr::filter(clarity%in%c("I1" ,  "SI2" , "SI1" , "VS2" , "VS1",  "VVS2")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(new_price = ifelse(cut == "Fair", 
                                   price/100000, 
                                   price/10))
```

As `Fair` and `Ideal` have different ranges of values, I created two separate plots for `Fair` and `Ideal` to be able to assign the breaks in y axis

I want the two axes in the two plots to have the same number of decimals. I used `fmt_decimals()` [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035786/ggplot2-y-axis-label-decimal-precision).

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
#function to assign decimals for axes
fmt_dcimals <- function(decimals=0){
  function(x) format(x,nsmall = decimals,scientific = FALSE)
}


f1 <- 
 ggplot(df[df$cut == "Fair",], aes(x=carat , y= new_price, color = color))+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3)+
  scale_y_continuous( limits = c(0,0.20), breaks=c(0, 0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2), labels = fmt_dcimals(2))+
  scale_x_continuous( limits = c(0,5.2), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5), labels = fmt_dcimals(2))+
  facet_wrap(~cut) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "")


f2 <- 
  ggplot(df[df$cut == "Ideal",], aes(x=carat , y= new_price, color = color))+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3)+
  scale_y_continuous( limits = c(0,2000), breaks=c(0, 250,500,750,1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000), labels = fmt_dcimals(2))+
  scale_x_continuous( limits = c(0,5.2), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5), labels = fmt_dcimals(2))+
  facet_wrap(~cut) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "")


f <- gridExtra::arrangeGrob(f1,f2, ncol=1, 
                            bottom=grid::textGrob(label= expression(Flow~(m^{3}~s^{-1})),
                                                  gp= gpar(fontsize=12, fontface="bold", col="black")),
                            left=grid::textGrob(label=expression(Concentration~mg~L^{-1}), rot=90, 
                                                gp= gpar(fontsize=12, fontface="bold", col="black")))

grid::grid.newpage() 
grid::grid.draw(f)
```

**RESULT**
[image]

The top and bottom plots are not aligned along x axis.

I can fix this using `ggarrange()` from `egg` package

```
library(egg)
f_1 <- ggarrange( f1, f2)
f_1
```

[image]

Now the two plots are perfectly aligned.

**QUESTIONS**

Any suggestions to align the two plots along x axis using `gridExtra`?
If not 
Can I add common labels for axes using `egg`?

and how can I add only **one legend** for the two plots?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @eipi10

I updated it as below

```
library(cowplot)
# Function to extract legend
# https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Share-a-legend-between-two-ggplot2-graphs
g_legend <-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend) }

# Extract legend as a grob
leg = g_legend(f1)

# Remove legend from plots
f1 = f1 + theme(legend.position = "none")
f2 = f2 + theme(legend.position = "none")

# Lay out the two
f_1 = plot_grid(f1, f2, ncol =1, align="v")

f_3 <- grid.arrange(
  arrangeGrob(f_1,  
              bottom=grid::textGrob(label= expression(Flow~(m^{3}~s^{-1})),
                                    gp= gpar(fontsize=12, fontface="bold", col="black")),
              left=grid::textGrob(label=expression(Concentration~mg~L^{-1}), rot=90, 
                                  gp= gpar(fontsize=12, fontface="bold", col="black"))),
  leg, 
  widths=c(9,1))
```

But it seems using `cowplot`, there is no vertical y line on the right side of the plot?

[image]

Comment: There are a bunch of questions like this on SO already. For example, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637261/perfectly-align-several-plots/38640937#38640937) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35301051/r-scatter-plot-matrix-using-ggplot2-with-themes-that-vary-by-facet-panel/35304121#35304121).

Comment: I suggest using facets with `scales = 'free_y'`.

Comment: @Axeman
Thanks for your time and help. As I mentioned in my question, the two plots have different ranges of values. facet_wrap doesn't allow me to control the break in y and x axes. In addition, it doesn't allow me to specify the number of decimals.

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Align-two-plots-on-a-page

Comment: @baptiste

Thanks for your time and help. Is it possible to add single x and y labels for more than one plot using your package egg?

Comment: you'd have to use low-level functions from the gtable package

Comment: RE: update, that's because `cowplot` sets it's own theme as default. Add another theme to override, such as the ggplot default `theme_grey()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can everything you want using only `ggplot2`, including a shared x-axis, shared axis titels and proper spacing. To me that seems easier than messing around with gtables.

This is a perfectly fine attempt:

```
ggplot(df[df$cut %in% c("Fair", "Ideal"),], aes(x=carat , y= new_price, color = color))+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = fmt_dcimals(2))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,5.2), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5), labels = fmt_dcimals(2))+
  facet_wrap(~cut, scales = 'free_y', nrow = 2) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "")
```

[image]

If you really want to have custom breaks, you can use a break function to supply those:

```
make_breaks <- function(ranges) {
  if(ranges[2] > 1) {
    c(0, 250,500,750,1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000)
  } else {
    c(0, 0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2)
  }
}

ggplot(df[df$cut %in% c("Fair", "Ideal"),], aes(x=carat , y= new_price, color = color))+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = fmt_dcimals(2), breaks = make_breaks)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,5.2), breaks=c(0,1,2,3,4,5), labels = fmt_dcimals(2))+
  facet_wrap(~cut, scales = 'free_y', nrow = 2) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But what if I have the breaks for one facet as 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 and for another facet 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35 (I mean both breaks are less than or equal 0.4)

Comment: I usually prefer to use facet_wrap() as it saves time and effort and produce fine results. It is the supervisors and reviewers who ask for these extra improvements (specific breaks) when it comes to publishing

Comment: Either give them the same breaks, or play around with values for `ranges[1]` or `ranges[2]`. If the data is different, they should be different.

Comment: If I modified df to have three levels in cut (Fair, Ideal and Good) df <- diamonds %>%
  dplyr::filter(cut%in%c("Fair","Ideal", "Good")) %>%
  dplyr::filter(clarity%in%c("I1" ,  "SI2" , "SI1" , "VS2" , "VS1",  "VVS2")) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(new_price = ifelse(cut == "Fair", price/100000,
                                   ifelse(cut == "Ideal", price/10,
                                          price / 1000)))

Any suggestions how to change make_breaks accordingly would be appreciated?

Comment: something like `make_breaks <- function(ranges) {
  if(ranges[2] > 1) {
    if (ranges[2] < 20) {
      c(0, 5, 10, 15)
    } else {
      c(0, 250,500,750,1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000)
    }
  } else {
    c(0, 0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2)
  }
}`